# msforeachdb with multiple queries into a single result set creating a temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to run a report to get some metrics about our users and the different applications we have. Each of our customers have a different database so I need to run the same queries across several databases. The query I use works like a charm but then I need to manually copy and paste each of the results to make everything readable. So I thought I would create a temp table, then insert each query result into a different column in the table to also avoid duplicate code but somehow, most of the results returned are null or show numbers that do not much when running the query without using the temp table. Any ideas as to what I am might be doing wrong? Can't seem to figure it out

```
DROP TABLE #ReportAlexis

CREATE TABLE #ReportAlexis
(
    CompanyName VARCHAR(MAX),
    TotalUsers INT,
    UsersSinceDate INT,
    TotalAppUsers INT,
    AppUsersSinceDate INT,
    Number_of_Logins_SinceDate INT,
);

EXEC master.dbo.sp_msforeachdb 'if ''?'' in (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'') return
declare @startdate DATETIME = ''2019-01-01''
INSERT INTO #ReportAlexis(Companyname) Select companyname from CompanyTable where Databasename = ?;

USE ?;
INSERT INTO #ReportAlexis(TotalUsers) Select count (*) as TotalUsers from User;
INSERT INTO #ReportAlexis(UsersSinceDate) Select count (*) as UsersSinceDate from User  where CreatedDate >= @startdate;
INSERT INTO #ReportAlexis(TotalAppUsers) Select count (*) as TotalAppUsers from Users where UserTypeID = 5;
INSERT INTO #ReportAlexis(AppUsersSinceDate) Select count (*) as AppUsersSinceDate from Users where UserTypeID = 5 and CreatedDate >=  @startdate;
INSERT INTO #ReportAlexis(Number_of_Logins_SinceDate) Select count (*) as Number_of_Logins_SinceDate from UserLoginDetails where UserID in (Select UserID from Users where UserTypeID = 5) and LoginTime >=  @startdate
'
SELECT * FROM #ReportAlexis
```

Comment: Do you intend to have 5 insert statements for each database?  From the description, it sounds as though you want one insert statement, with 5 columns to be inserted.  INSERT INTO #ReportAlexis (TotalUsers, UsersSinceDate,TotalAppUsers, AppUsersSinceDate, Number_of_Logins_SinceDate) SELECT....

Comment: Please stop using that procedure, it's undocumented and unsupported because it's riddled with bugs. See [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5686/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-using-spineachdb/), [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/), and [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/).

Comment: Mr. Bertand is a very well deserved SQL Server MVP and I have used his replacement mentioned in the links above and it works well. The stackoverflow community is fortunate that we have Mr. Betrand involved with this forum.

Comment: RobertSievers yes, 5 different inserts with 5 totally unrelated numbers, AaronBertrand yeah I was aware it was buggy I guess I will have to do it the hard way, thanks for the links will read them and hopefully learn a thing or two

Answer (score 0):

I assume the scope is disconnected, try a ##table (global temp table). the #table is only easily accessible within scope though the real name can be found in:

```
select t.name from tempdb.sys.tables t where t.name like '#ReportAlexis%'

/* it's still better to use a global temp table */

CREATE TABLE ##ReportAlexis
(
    CompanyName VARCHAR(MAX),
    TotalUsers INT,
    UsersSinceDate INT,
    TotalAppUsers INT,
    AppUsersSinceDate INT,
    Number_of_Logins_SinceDate INT,
);
```

Comment: Actually a better way to find *only your copy of the table* is to use `... WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#ReportAlexis');` - but that is of little value, because what can you do with the full name once you have it?